# if I want to code mobile games using java which game engine should I use

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, coronasdk, google-play-games, 2d-games

can I code games using java language and which engine should I use 
according to my knowledge unity uses C# and java script

any help will be appriciated

Comment: U r developing this in android ?

Comment: yes in android.

Comment: I can provide the list of game engine now available in market for android I post this as an answer. It may help you

Comment: You might want to provide more information about the type of game and the technologies you expect it to depend on. A game that is meant to be VR and 3D will likely be developed with a different game engine framework than tetris. More context will help you get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can list you the game engine used in android now.Please check. It will help you.You have to pick a game engine according to your requirement.

List of 3D engine [Check](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/2)

List of 2D engine [Check](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/1)

Comment: I prefer lidgdx it is more advance now for android

Comment: can I use libgdx for 2d and 3d games?

Comment: Yes its support both ..